# Default scroll position of HTML select and option tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

When I first click select, the previous value is located at the bottom of the scroll bar.

[This is a default. I don't want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocUTo.png)

I want to place it on top as **a default**. Is it possible?

[I need like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJ0GU.png)

My code of this part looks like that.(React JSX)

```js
const Index = () => {
  const inputTime = [{
      input: "08:00AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 08:00:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "08:10AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 08:10:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "08:20AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 08:20:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "08:30AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 08:30:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "08:40AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 08:40:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "08:50AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 08:50:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "09:00AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 09:00:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "09:10AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 09:10:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "09:20AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 09:20:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "09:30AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 09:30:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "09:40AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 09:40:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "09:50AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 09:50:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "10:00AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 10:00:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "10:10AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 10:10:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "10:20AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 10:20:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "10:30AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 10:30:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "10:40AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 10:40:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "10:50AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 10:50:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "11:00AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 11:00:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "11:10AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 11:10:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "11:20AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 11:20:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "11:30AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 11:30:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "11:40AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 11:40:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "11:50AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 11:50:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "12:00PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 12:00:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "12:10PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 12:10:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "12:20PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 12:20:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "12:30PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 12:30:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "12:40PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 12:40:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "12:50PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 12:50:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "01:00PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 13:00:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "01:10PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 13:10:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "01:20PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 13:20:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "01:30PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 13:30:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "01:40PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 13:40:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "01:50PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 13:50:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "02:00PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 14:00:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "02:10PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 14:10:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "02:20PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 14:20:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "02:30PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 14:30:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "02:40PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 14:40:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "02:50PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 14:50:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "03:00PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 15:00:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "03:10PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 15:10:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "03:20PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 15:20:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "03:30PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 15:30:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "03:40PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 15:40:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "03:50PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 15:50:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "04:00PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 16:00:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "04:10PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 16:10:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "04:20PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 16:20:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "04:30PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 16:30:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "04:40PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 16:40:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "04:50PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 16:50:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "05:00PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 17:00:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "05:10PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 17:10:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "05:20PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 17:20:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "05:30PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 17:30:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "05:40PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 17:40:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "05:50PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 17:50:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "06:00PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 18:00:00.000"
    },

  ];


  const dbdata = {
    employeeName: "Richard Roe",
    trade: "Roofer",
    workFrom: "1900-01-01 07:30:00.000",
    mealFrom: "1900-01-01 13:00:00.000",
    mealTo: "1900-01-01 13:30:00.000",
    workTo: "1900-01-01 17:30:00.000",
    laborHours: "9.5",
  }
  return ( < select value = {
      dbdata.mealTo
    } > {
      inputTime.map(inputTime => ( <
        option key = {
          inputTime.time
        }
        value = {
          inputTime.time
        } > {
          inputTime.input
        } <
        /option>
      ))
    } <
    /select>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render( < Index / > , document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

(I don't want to use Jquery because I'm using React)

Is there way to fix this?
I've searched a lot, but I don't have any information about this. Only jquery.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please indicate what you have tried, and a minimal selection of relevant code. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi, Can you please provide you code snippet, so it can be easy for community to verify your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Index = () => {
  const inputTime = [{
      input: "08:00AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 08:00:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "08:10AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 08:10:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "08:20AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 08:20:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "08:30AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 08:30:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "08:40AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 08:40:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "08:50AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 08:50:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "09:00AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 09:00:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "09:10AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 09:10:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "09:20AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 09:20:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "09:30AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 09:30:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "09:40AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 09:40:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "09:50AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 09:50:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "10:00AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 10:00:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "10:10AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 10:10:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "10:20AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 10:20:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "10:30AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 10:30:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "10:40AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 10:40:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "10:50AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 10:50:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "11:00AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 11:00:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "11:10AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 11:10:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "11:20AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 11:20:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "11:30AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 11:30:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "11:40AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 11:40:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "11:50AM",
      time: "1900-01-01 11:50:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "12:00PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 12:00:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "12:10PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 12:10:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "12:20PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 12:20:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "12:30PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 12:30:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "12:40PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 12:40:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "12:50PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 12:50:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "01:00PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 13:00:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "01:10PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 13:10:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "01:20PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 13:20:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "01:30PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 13:30:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "01:40PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 13:40:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "01:50PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 13:50:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "02:00PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 14:00:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "02:10PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 14:10:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "02:20PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 14:20:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "02:30PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 14:30:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "02:40PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 14:40:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "02:50PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 14:50:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "03:00PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 15:00:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "03:10PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 15:10:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "03:20PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 15:20:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "03:30PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 15:30:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "03:40PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 15:40:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "03:50PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 15:50:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "04:00PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 16:00:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "04:10PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 16:10:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "04:20PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 16:20:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "04:30PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 16:30:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "04:40PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 16:40:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "04:50PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 16:50:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "05:00PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 17:00:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "05:10PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 17:10:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "05:20PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 17:20:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "05:30PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 17:30:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "05:40PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 17:40:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "05:50PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 17:50:00.000"
    },
    {
      input: "06:00PM",
      time: "1900-01-01 18:00:00.000"
    },

  ];


  const dbdata = {
    employeeName: "Richard Roe",
    trade: "Roofer",
    workFrom: "1900-01-01 07:30:00.000",
    mealFrom: "1900-01-01 13:00:00.000",
    mealTo: "1900-01-01 13:30:00.000",
    workTo: "1900-01-01 17:30:00.000",
    laborHours: "9.5",
  }
  return ( < select  > {
      inputTime.map(inputTime => ( <
        option key = {
          inputTime.time
        }
        selected = { inputTime.time===dbdata.mealTo }
        value = {
          inputTime.time
        } > {
          inputTime.input
        } <
        /option>
      ))
    } <
    /select>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render( < Index / > , document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```